# Full Outer Join in SQL using INTO keyword

Tags: sql

Say I have two tables such as -

[image]

and I want -

[image]

The dot after Kay in the output is not necessary and I can do without that.
How does one go about achieving this in SQL? I want to specify the output table in the query as well.

Comment: Do a `FULL OUTER JOIN`. (Just what your teacher told you to do...)

Comment: Yes the above than you can add a case to replace null with dot for age.

Comment: So I am using a proprietary software which allows for SQL statements and if I do a full outer join in it it says table column names in the result table should be unique, which leads me to believe the it is not combining the two index cols together

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Maybe you did `select * from a join b on a.id = b.id`, thus getting the ID twice and the software you are using has problems with this. In that case specify which columns you want to select explicitly (`select coalesce(a.id, b.id) as id, ...`) or replace the `ON` clause with a `USING` clause (`select * from a join b using (id)`).

Answer (score 1):

In the future, please provide the RDMS you're using (the type of SQL, like SQL Server, or MySQL) and the example data in text format instead of an image.

Also, the INTO keyword is not enough information on its own. There are two ways this can be done, shown below, using INSERT INTO...SELECT or SELECT INTO...

[DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8e86c883b1361266aa139b2a785e75dd) I used SQL Server for this example. You may need to change a few things to make it work for you.

You also may find an [explainer on outer joins helpful](https://www.essentialsql.com/get-ready-to-learn-sql-server-14-introduction-to-outer-joins/). The FULL OUTER JOIN can be a little confusing when you get started.

```
CREATE TABLE FileOne
( ID char(3)
, Name char(3)
);

CREATE TABLE FileTwo
( ID char(3)
, Age int
, Sex char(1)
);

CREATE TABLE Destination
(ID char(3)
, Name char(3)
, Age int
, Sex char(1)
);

INSERT INTO FileOne (ID, Name)
VALUES
 ('A01','SUE')
,('A02','TOM')
,('A05','KAY')
,('A10','JIM');

INSERT INTO FileTwo (ID, Age,Sex)
VALUES
 ('A01',58,'F')
,('A02',20,'M')
,('A04',47,'F')
,('A10',11,'M');


INSERT INTO Destination (ID, Name, Age, Sex)
SELECT
    COALESCE(f1.ID, f2.ID) as FullID
  , f1.Name
  , f2.Age
  , f2.Sex
FROM FileOne f1
FULL OUTER JOIN FileTwo f2
ON f1.ID = f2.ID;

-- alternative
SELECT
    COALESCE(f1.ID, f2.ID) as FullID
  , f1.Name
  , f2.Age
  , f2.Sex
INTO AltDest
FROM FileOne f1
FULL OUTER JOIN FileTwo f2
ON f1.ID = f2.ID


SELECT * FROM Destination;
SELECT * FROM AltDest;
```

Answer (score 1):

In standard SQL the syntax would be:

```
create table output as
    select *(
    from fileone f1 full join
         filetwo f2
         using (id);
```

Not all databases support all aspects of this syntax.